# Passing json results

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have the following json response:

> {"data":[{"series":{"id":"15404","series_code":"TOS","publisher_id":"280","series_short_name":"Tales
>   of
>   Suspense","start_year":"1959","end_year":"1968","published":"1959-1968","type_id":"1","no_issues":"99","published_gcd":"January
>   1959-March 1968","series_long_name":"Tales of Suspense (Marvel
>   1959-1968)","volume":"1","first_issue":"1","last_issue":"99","comment":"","created_date":"2013-03-24
>   01:00:00","user_id":"1","last_updated":"2013-03-24
>   01:00:00","note":"","is_active":"1","wiki_stem":null}}],"error":"boo"}

Here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/series/lookup?year='+json.IssueYear+'&title='+json.Title,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.error) {
          alert(response.error);
          console.log(response.error);
        }
        else {
          //console.log(response.content);
          alert(response.data[0].series.id);
        }
        },
        error: function(e) {
          alert("An error occurred: " + e.responseText.message);
            console.log(e);
          }
        });
```

I would have thought that this would return the id but it says data is undefined?

> alert(response.data[0].series.id)

I must be missing something, any help appreciated.

Comment: should work, where are you putting the alert?

Comment: Did you parsed id back to an object if it was a `json` string?

Comment: Works for me. Could you provide more context or a fiddle?

Comment: in the success method of the jquery .ajax call. If I alert(response) it returns the json above, so it is reading the response properly?

Comment: `console.log(typeof response); console.dir(response);`

Comment: @squeaker: You need to parse this JSON to an object, it's probably still a string.  `JSON.parse(response);`.

Comment: @Rocket - top man. thanks. I was missing dataType: 'json'

Answer (score 0):

Need a little bit more information.  How are you getting the response back to your code? if this was JQuery, I know that this would work:

```
$.post("/path/to/script.php", {
    var1: 'test',
    var2: 'test2'
}, function(response) {
    alert(response.data[0].series.id); // This will work here
}, 'json');
```

That said, this little snippet shows what would work.  Without know what your javascript code is, it makes it very near impossible to determine if what you are doing is right or wrong.